# Spelling mistakes - Pyenchant

Tags: python, rtf, pyenchant

I tried using python library for spell-check,correcting and replacing.

For some complex spelling correction, I need to have a second opinion and to see replaced word underlined or strike through.

Even if the file output is in rtf format, it is ok. How to solve it?

Efforts so far.

```
import enchant
    from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
    chkr = SpellChecker("en_UK","en_US")
    spacedfile = "This is a setence. It has speeelinng mistake."
    chkr.set_text(spacedfile)
    for err in chkr:
        sug = err.suggest()[0]
        err.replace(sug)
    Spellchecked = chkr.get_text()
    print Spellchecked
```

Output:

```
This is a sentence. It has spelling mistake.
```

Expected outcome:

```
This is a **sntence** sentence. It has **speeelinng** spelling mistake."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do the replacement including the `**misspelledword**` part.

```
import enchant
from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
chkr = SpellChecker("en_UK","en_US")
spacedfile = "This is a setence. It has speeelinng mistake."
chkr.set_text(spacedfile)
for err in chkr:
    sug = err.suggest()[0]
    err.replace("**%s** %s" % (err.word, sug))  # Look here
Spellchecked = chkr.get_text()
print Spellchecked
```