# Spelling correction in sentences

Tags: python, regex, spelling

I use https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html to find spelling errors

How to find and replace misspelt words in a sentence.

Efforts so far:

```
sentences = "This sntence cntins errors. This sentence has to be corrcted."
list_string = sentences.split(' ') 
for word in list_string:
    print(correction(word))
```

Output:

```
this
sentence
contains
error
this
sentence
has
to
be
corrected.
```

Expected output:

```
This <<sntence>> sentence <<cntins>> contains errors. This sentence has to be <<corrcted>> corrected.
```

Able to achieve it using [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123861/spelling-mistakes-pyenchant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123861/spelling-mistakes-pyenchant) How to find and replace misspelt words into original text while retaining misspelt words within << >>

Comment: What's your question? What's wrong with the answer you linked to?

Comment: What's a "direct approach"? Why are more approaches needed? Your spell checking module isn't very good by the way, it doesn't recognise the word "error".

Comment: Got answer. the error is based on big.txt and it might not have contained close word. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str.join` to a generator:

```
print(' '.join('<<'+i+'>>'+' %s'%correction(i) if correction(i) != i else i for i in sentences.split()))
```